# Magento Mirasvit Search Cannot instantiate interface

Tags: magento2

> Cannot instantiate interface
>   Magento\Elasticsearch\Model\Adapter\FieldMapper\Product\FieldProvider\FieldName\ResolverInterface

Answer (score 0):

Did you do setup compile? Please run setup compile.

```
php bin/magento s:s:d
```

Comment: Fatal error: Interface 'Vertex\Tax\Model\Flexfield\Processor\InvoiceFlexFieldProcessorInterface' not found in /var/www/au/releases/20191107071806/vendor/vertex/module-tax/Model/FlexField/Processor/OrderCurrencyGetterProcessor.php on line 24
this error come when run di

Comment: i run compiled succesfully but issue still not resolved

Answer (score 0):

**Reason:**

The elasticsearch php library wasn’t installed in Magento 2.

This issue is possible only if Elastic Search Ultimate was installed without using composer (manual installation). And not all steps from user manual were completed.

**Solution:**

```
composer require elasticsearch/elasticsearch:~5.1
```

This command will install elasticsearch php library (for ES 5.1/6.2) and additional required libraries.